# while true do... without the window crashing

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have tgis problem , I have a button in my tkinter window that calls a python function that does for exemple :

```
While True :
    n=n+1
    print n #to check if the function is really called upon button press
```

When i check in the python console everything works perfectly but in the window the button freezes and the window crashes...
My question is : is there a way for calling functions like these without crashing ? This is'nt the first time I have had problems like these , I had the same problem using kivy , seems it can't be done on GUI programs ?

Comment: your program isn't crashing -- it's doing exactly what you told it to do. It is in an infinite loop, which is preventing the event loop from processing any events until the loop completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tkinter, the conventional approach is to use `after` which will cause the target function to execute after a certain amount of time.

```
def some_function():
    global n
    n += 1
    print n
    root.after(100, some_function)

root.after(100, some_function)
```

Now `some_function` will execute every 100 milliseconds. These periodic delays give the GUI system some much-needed time to redraw its windows and clear its event queue, so it doesn't lock up.

---

You can also use `after_idle`, which is like `after`, except it executes your function as soon as the GUI system is no longer busy.

Comment: What if for example I have have two different functions( function 'a()' and 'b()'  for exemple which both have for loops in them and i need these functions in a while True statrment how would that be done ? @kevin

Comment: Same as in `some_function`, I guess, except you replace the "incrementing n" stuff with calling `a` and `b`.

Comment: I think I see , I will try and tell you what happens, and the root. is the root = tk() ?

Comment: `def start_f() :
    user_= e4.get()
    interval= e5.get()
    times= e6.get()
    

    while True :
        function1(user_,times)
        sleep(60*int(interval))
        function2()`  start_f() is called when a button is pressed now what do i need to do so it doesnt freeze?

Comment: could you please explain ? @Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Your never-ending function executes in the same thread as the GUI. Since your function does not return, the GUI is never refreshed. It is frozen.

You may start your `while True` function in a separate thread to let the GUI refresh regularly and catch a Cancel button, or an exit command. Then the GUI can set `end_function` variable to `True`. In your loop, check the variable and break if asked to.

See [help about threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Untested code to illustrate the idea:

```
from threading import Thread

class Worker(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self._end_function = False

    def stop(self):
        self._end_function = True

    def run(self):
        while not self._end_function:
            print("I'm working hard.")
```

In you main code, instantiate `Worker`, and when the button is pressed, call Worker.start() (not Worker.run(), see help.). Then, upon user action (Cancel, quit,...), call Worker.stop().

Comment: What should I use instead of an infinity loop then if i want the program to repeatedly do the same thing until it is exited ? And could you please explain how to use a different thread in this case ? Thank you @Jérôme

Comment: @Amroelaswar: OK, I get the infinite loop idea. I updated my answer to tell a bit more about threading.

Comment: I used your idea of threading as it seemed most adequat but i keep getting this error when i put the arguments of the function i want to thread :  `thread.start_new_thread(unf7, (times))
TypeError: 2nd arg must be a tuple` you know what this means ? @Jérôme

Comment: @Amroelaswar: I have no insights and no time for searching right now so I can't comment on what you are doing, but `(times)` is not a tuple. Try `thread.start_new_thread(unf7, (times,))`. This is a typical Python issue. `(a)` is not a tuple, `(a,)` is.